# how to enforce @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) in EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following mapping:

```
public enum JobType {
    CLEANER,
    CRAWLER, ...
 }


public class JobId implements Serializable {
    private int accId;
    private String env;
    private JobType jobType;
 }

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class JobExecution {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "accId", column = @Column(name = "acc_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "env", column = @Column(name = "env")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "jobType", column = @Column(name = "agg_type")) })
    private JobId jobId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "Job_STATUS")
    private JobStatus jobStatus;

    //...  other staff 
}
```

The job status enum column is writen OK with string value in it.

But the jobType is written it's ordinal value (0,1,...) and not the name (CLEANER, CRAWLER ...).

I want to write into the database the JobType enum name and not it's ordinal() value.

Which mapping can I add to the @EmbeddedId to hint this property for jobType column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is by using the [@Enumerated annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) directly on the field:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

If needed, I guess you could annotate your `JobId` class with `@Embeddable` and then put the `@Enumerated` annotation on your `JobType` field:

```
@Embeddable
public class JobId implements Serializable {
    private int accId;
    private String env;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private JobType jobType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought. I just did not wanted to put annotation to JobId class since it is places in common package that does not have a dependency for jpa

Comment: That would couple embeddable value object to `javax.persistence` (which would break your architecture rules if any). However I don't see other solution for now.